# MIPS Memory Mapped IO received byte causing error

Tags: memory, io, mips

For university, im attemting to use Memory Mapped IO to take in 6 characters store them in a buffer, then print the buffer. The below code i the receiver, $t0 is the adddess of the reciever. It checks if the receiver is ready, if so receives the data. Right now im just attempting to make sure im getting the data. So im attempting to print it, but im receiving a syntax error and I cant work out why.

Reason I think is it might be that the byte received isnt compatible.

```
lw   $t1, 0($t0)           # receiver control
andi $t1, $t1,0x0001       # check if ready
beq  $t1, $zero,readloop   # if not ready
lb   $s0, 4($t0)           # receiver data

li  $v0, 11               # print char
li  $a0, $s0              # takes address of string as argument <--- This is where the compiler is saying theres a syntax error
syscall
```

Comment: Very hard to comment on snippets of code.

Comment: Well, what is `li  $a0, $s0` even supposed to do? `li` is for loading immediates, and `$s0` is not an immediate. It's possible that `move` is the appropriate instruction to use, but it's hard to tell with the limited information you've given us.